# GPS Lat Lon Issue in Blackberry Storm

Tags: blackberry

I Write the following code in my application.
It will run successfully in Simulator but while i m trying to run in my device then it gives Lat & Lon (0.0,0.0).
What is the problem.

My Code is .

```
public class GetLatLon extends TimerTask{
public static Timer timer;
private double longitude;
private double latitude;

public GetLatLon(int duration) {
    timer = new Timer();
    try {
        // TODO: update criteria with desired location distances, etc
        LocationProvider.getInstance(new Criteria()).setLocationListener(
                new MyLocationListener(), 1, 1, 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }

    timer.schedule(this, 0, 10000);
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Lattitude :-"+ latitude);
    System.out.println("Longitude :-"+ longitude);       
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider provider, Location location) {
    if (location != null && location.isValid()) {
        QualifiedCoordinates qc = location.getQualifiedCoordinates()
                     try {
        GetLatLon.this.longitude = qc.getLongitude();
        GetLatLon.this.latitude = qc.getLatitude();
        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.err.println("criccomini " + e.toString());
        }
        } else {
            System.err.println("criccomini location not valid");
        }
    }

    public void providerStateChanged(LocationProvider provider, int newState) {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have internet Contection in my device But don't have BIS Service.
Is BIS Service compalsury to Get GPSlocation.?

Comment: which model device do you have means test?

Comment: I have used Blackberry Storm.

Comment: I am Not getting Gps in my device please any one help me. 
My Device is Blackberry 9500.
My Location is Ahmedabad (India).
I have active BIS Service.

Please Any one Tell ME what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had also faced same problem with 9550 Storm-2.
I think you face the problem due to your device GPS value does not initiate properly. Try to use this tool :

http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/12255

this will initiate the GPS values(Plz don't close this tool just send it to background by pressing red key).After initiate the GPS value try to run you application.

i hope  problem will be solved. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here No issue with code 
Gps is not supported 5.0 OS with LAN ,so
I provide you some guides please verify.

[Introduction to GPS and BlackBerry](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Introduction-to-GPS-and-BlackBerry/ta-p/446853) video.

[The BlackBerry smartphone models and their corresponding GPS capabilities](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/The-BlackBerry-smartphone-models-and-their-corresponding-GPS/ta-p/445329)

[How to detect whether my BB device has GPS support?](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-detect-whether-my-BB-device-has-GPS-support/m-p/52922#M5759)

Some [GPS Related Issues](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/GPS-Issues/m-p/393760#M76430)

[Best practices for designing GPS applications for BlackBerry smartphones operating on CDMA networks](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Best-practices-for-designing-GPS-applications-for-BlackBerry/ta-p/445310)

this is full information about blackberry GPS support

Comment: Blackberry 9550 Storm.
And Use Mobile Internet Network for GPS.

I m not using BIS Service.

Comment: after verified if you know any doubts then let me know?

Comment: hi vijay just click on last one video it gives you answer

Comment: I have one Question.
Is BIS service is Compulsory required for GPS or not.?

Comment: i think in in OS 5 should require cellular connection

Comment: I can appreciate linking all the information here, but it seems you've just searched for anything BlackBerry and GPS and thrown it into the answer.  How does this specifically resolve the question regarding getting 0.0 as the latitude and longitude?

Comment: hi Michael Donohue, i gave this answer because he have doubt that "I have internet Contection in my device But don't have BIS Service. Is BIS Service compalsury to Get GPSlocation.? – vijay.jangid07 17 hours ago" there is no issue with code