# Get coordinates via GPS in blackberry

Tags: gps, location, blackberry-simulator

I am calling startLocationUpdate() in BlackBerry simulator 9800 to get coordinates (latitude,longitude) of where I am, i.e. in UAE. However I get coordinates for Canada. What does this mean? Is the GPS not working? I tried checking settings for the simulator and I do not see any option to "turn GPS on". Please guide how to obtain my current location.

```
private boolean startLocationUpdate()
    {
        boolean retval = false;

            try
            {
            locationProvider = LocationProvider.getInstance(null);

            if ( locationProvider == null )
            {

            Runnable showGpsUnsupportedDialog = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {

                Dialog.alert("GPS is not supported on this platform, exiting...");
                //System.exit( 1 );
                }
            };

            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait( showGpsUnsupportedDialog ); // Ask event-dispatcher thread to display dialog ASAP.
            }
            else
            {

            locationProvider.setLocationListener(new LocationListenerImpl(), interval, -1, -1);

            retval = true;
            }
            }
            catch (LocationException le)
            {
                System.err.println("Failed to instantiate the LocationProvider object, exiting...");
                System.err.println(le);
                System.exit(0);
            }
            return retval;
            }

            private class LocationListenerImpl implements LocationListener
            {

            public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider provider, Location location)
            {
                    if(location.isValid())
                    {
                        longitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();
                        latitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude();

                        updateLocationScreen(latitude, longitude);              

                    }
            }

            public void providerStateChanged(LocationProvider provider, int newState)
            {
            }
        }

         private void updateLocationScreen(final double latitude, final double longitude)
            {
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
                    {
                    public void run()
                    {
                    lat = latitude;
                    longt = longitude;


                    RichTextField txt=new RichTextField();
                    txt.setText("Long=="+longt);

                    RichTextField txt1=new RichTextField();
                    txt1.setText("lat=="+lat);

                    add(txt);
                    add(txt1);


//                  persistentLatitude.setContents(Double.toString(latitude));
//                  persistentLongitude.setContents(Double.toString(longitude));



                    }
                    });
            }
```

I would like to check for both GPS and internet (Wifi,BES,GPRS/edge etc) and whichever connection is available, I would like to acquire coordinates through the available service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default GPS location in BB Simulators is set to a position in CANADA (Waterloo as far as I remember), that's why you are getting the coordinates of CANADA. You can change the GPS location from 'Simulate->GPS Location' in BB Simulator.
[This video from BB SupportForums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/How-to-Simulate-GPS-Functionality/ta-p/446892?name=GPSSimNew) may help you.

The following links may also be helpful:

1. [SO Answer for 'BlackBerry GPS Application'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738198/blackberry-gps-application)
2. [API for BlackberryLocation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/gps/BlackBerryLocation.html)

For connectivity issues see this [link](http://develop-for-fun.blogspot.com/2011/05/blackberry-connectivity-issues.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links. The video from BB SupportForums to turn GPS from the simulator. I am using BlackBerry Plugin for Eclipse and there is no such option for that. I spent a whole day but I do not see anywhere where I can turn on GPS from. Where do I turn GPS from in Eclipse BlackBerry Plugin?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use Eclipse Blackberry Plugin or JDE, the 9800 simulator that runs must be the same for both. You should look for the 'Simulate --> GPS Locations...' options after running the simulator ... not within the Eclipse environment.

Comment: @Sarah, Look at the Menu bar of the simulator when running your application. Then you will see 'Simulate --> GPS Locations...' option.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I got it now. My mistake, didnt look it up properly. Thanks.

Comment: @HeartBeat, I was going to do it anyways, before your comment:) The links are useful to me. Thanks.

Comment: I got the GPS Location turned on but I still get coordinates for Waterloo. Is it not supposed to give me the correct coordinates now?

Comment: There is no 'Turning on of GPS Location' in BB Simulators, you need to change the coordinates from that 'GPS Location' prompt. And I hope you're not expecting to get 'your' physical location to be detected by the simulator. You'll just get the location that you're going to set there instead the default location (Waterloo, CANADA I think).

Comment: oh ok. This is my first BB app,I'm learning along the way. I will now try to get location through Wifi to see what I can get.